# Change Values in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe filled with several columns. I need to change the values of a column for data normalization like in the following example:

```
User_id   
751730951     
751730951
0
163526844
...and so on
```

I need to replace every value in the column that is not 0 (string) in a into something like "is not empty". I have tried it now for hours but still cannot change every value that is not 0 into something else. Replace()-function don't work really good for that. Some good ideas?

EDIT (my solution):

```
finalResult.loc[finalResult['update_user'] == '0', 'update_user'] = 'empty'
finalResult.loc[finalResult['update_user'] != 'empty', 'update_user'] = 'not empty'
```

Comment: So `df['User_id'] = df['User_id'].replace('0', 'is not empty')` does not work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df.loc[df['mycolumn'] != '0', 'mycolumn'] = 'not empty'
```

or if the value is an int,

```
df.loc[df['mycolumn'] != 0, 'mycolumn'] = 'not empty'
```

`df.loc[rows, cols]` allows you to get or set a range of values in your DataFrame. First parameter is rows, in which case I'm using a boolean mask to get all rows that don't have a 0 in `mycolumn`. The second parameter is the column you want to get/set. Since I'm replacing the same column I queried from, it is also `mycolumn`.

I then simply using the assignment operator to assign the value of 'not empty' like you wanted.

### New column containing 'not empty'

If you want a new column to contain the 'not empty' so you're not contaminating your original data in `mycolumn`, you can do:

```
df.loc[df['mycolumn'] != 0, 'myNewColumnsName'] = 'not empty'
```

Answer (score 4):

Simpliest is use:

```
df['User_id'] = df['User_id'].replace('0', 'is not empty')
```

If `0` is `int`:

```
df['User_id'] = df['User_id'].replace(0, 'is not empty')
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we use a Series with the data specified in the question, named user_id, with a single line you do what you need:

```
user_id.where(user_id == 0).fillna('is not empty')
```

I don't like loc very much since I think it complicates the reading.

It might be better than replace because it allows the opposite case:

```
user_id.where(user_id != 0).fillna('is empty')
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Can you describe how this is different and any key reasons it would produce the desired result?